# В AlertDialog передать текст с ListView?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Доброго времени суток!. Как можно в Xamarin Forms (Potable iOS, Android, WP) занести данные в AlertDialog из ListView при нажатий ItemTapped?

```
        ItemTapped += (sender, position) =>
        {
            var IdCommercia = position.Item as DepartmentReitingCommercialItemsViewCell;
            if (IdCommercia == null)
                return;

            OnAlertMessage()

            SelectedItem = null;
        };

    async void OnAlertMessage()
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Предупреждение!", "сервис недоступен", "Ок");
    }
```

Вот пример, который сделан на Android (Android Studio)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]